# shell tab-completion of strings based on more than just the first characters?

Tags: shell, character, tab-completion

Are there any shells which support tab-completion of strings based on more than just the first characters?

For example, say I have the branch `add_page_to_site`, when I do `git checkout si[TAB]`, it expands to `git checkout add_page_to_site`.

Are there any shells that support this? zsh? fish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there isn't - that's a shame =)

Answer (score 0):

That is called bash-completion. It's a package on most distros.

Comment: Umm, bash completion only works when you match exactly the starting characters - in this case I'll have to type: `git checkout add[TAB]`. Or does it have a feature I'm not aware of?

Comment: Sorry, I had gotten you wrong. No, that's not featured, but you could probably hack bash-completion. (I don't think it's in any other shell either because it's just to complicated to be usable). And you can always `git checkout [TAB][TAB]` and then find your item in the list of all "possible" next arguments in the very rare cases where you only know something that is not a prefix.